# Pandas - Local store a variable (multiplier)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Another question :) I need to know how to store a variable for reference at the beginning of my script. In this case, I am needing to store an FX conversion rate which I want to be able to adjust at the beginning of the script. I am also wanting to store a directory in my PC which will store the outputs of the script and is prone to changing, each month.

For reference, I have created the following example.

```
import pandas as pd
FX_rate = {'AUD':[0.71442],'NZD':[0.68476]}
Dir = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\December\Monthly_Output.csv'

df = {'AU_SALES':[1000,2500,750,6800,1000],'NZ_SALES':[500,2200,430,100,6670]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)

# ISSUE HERE - Covert Sales using FX_rate dictionary
df_USDAUD = df['AU_SALES'] * FX_rate['AUD']
df_USDNZD = df['NZ_SALES'] * FX_rate['NZD']

df_converted = df_USDAUD.append(df_USDNZD)

# Save output in folder, using Dir directory
df_converted.to_csv(Dir)
```

If I were to run this script I would get an error telling me that the number of values in df['AU_SALES'] (5) and the number of values in FX_rate['AUD'] (1) do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your expected output should be but I think this should work. Use `multiply` with the start operator `*`

```
import pandas as pd
FX_rate = {'AUD':[0.71442],'NZD':[0.68476]}
Dir = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\December\Monthly_Output.csv'

df = {'AU_SALES':[1000,2500,750,6800,1000],'NZ_SALES':[500,2200,430,100,6670]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)

# use multiply with the star operator
df_USDAUD = df1['AU_SALES'].multiply(*FX_rate['AUD'])
df_USDNZD = df1['NZ_SALES'].multiply(*FX_rate['NZD'])

df_converted = df_USDAUD.append(df_USDNZD)
print(df_converted)

0     714.4200
1    1786.0500
2     535.8150
3    4858.0560
4     714.4200
0     342.3800
1    1506.4720
2     294.4468
3      68.4760
4    4567.3492
dtype: float64
```

Or you can create a function

```
# create a function
def myFun(df, aud, nzd, Dir):
    df_USDAUD = df['AU_SALES'] * aud
    df_USDNZD = df['NZ_SALES'] * nzd
    df_converted = df_USDAUD.append(df_USDNZD)
    df_converted.to_csv(Dir)
    return df_converted

Dir = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\December\Monthly_Output.csv'

df = {'AU_SALES':[1000,2500,750,6800,1000],'NZ_SALES':[500,2200,430,100,6670]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)

myFun(df1, 0.71442, 0.68476, Dir)
```

or just do not store the numbers in a list inside the dict: `FX_rate = {'AUD':0.71442,'NZD':0.68476}`

```
FX_rate = {'AUD':0.71442,'NZD':0.68476}
Dir = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\December\Monthly_Output.csv'

df = {'AU_SALES':[1000,2500,750,6800,1000],'NZ_SALES':[500,2200,430,100,6670]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)

# use multiple with the star operator
df_USDAUD = df1['AU_SALES'] * FX_rate['AUD']
df_USDNZD = df1['NZ_SALES'] * FX_rate['NZD']

df_converted = df_USDAUD.append(df_USDNZD)
print(df_converted)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is just what I am looking for